# Alphabetize a comma delimited string in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm not quite sure where to head from here, I have a small bit of code that loops through a table and writes all of the field names to a string for use as a value rowsource in a combo box.  I'd like these items to be alphabetized but am not quite sure the best way to go about doing this with a string variable (or in the combo boxes RowSource property).

Any thoughts or suggestions on the best way to do this?

If it's helpful here is the code I have:

```
Dim strFields As String
Dim fldTemp As Field
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim setData As DAO.Recordset

Set setData = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblEnvironment WHERE 1 = 2")

For Each fldTemp In setData.Fields
    strFields = strFields & ", " & fldTemp.Name
Next

strFields = Mid(strFields, 3)

For intCount = 1 To 10
    Controls("cboField" & intCount).RowSource = strFields
Next
```

StrFields is what I would like to alphabatize.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you just put an ORDER BY clause on your OpenRecordset query?

Comment: I could if it was values in a field, but this is pulling the names of all the fields, not the values within them.  This recordset actually returns no data other than the field names because of the WHERE 1 = 2 statement.

Comment: What type of connection is `CurrentDb`?

Comment: Sorry, it's in Access, CurrentDB just references the DB the from resides in - Access 2010 / Jet Engine.

Comment: Maybe just create your own UDT instead of using a string to read in all the variables? like sorted list... (ArrayList?) The equivalent would be Collection I believe...

Comment: When you want the field names for a table, you needn't open a recordset to get them.  You can just walk the table's `TableDef.Fields` collection like this ... `For Each fldTemp In CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblEnvironment").Fields`

Comment: Thanks HansUp, I've applied this to Sean's answer below and now have cleaner code that does what I need!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would convert the string you are creating to an array, and then sort that array. You could then use `Join` to convert the array to a comma delimited string

using the bubble sort found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/830b42cf-8c97-4aaf-b34b-d860773281f7/sorting-an-array-in-vba-without-excel-function) this is what I would adjust your code to be

```
Dim strFields As String
Dim fldTemp As Field
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim setData As DAO.Recordset
Dim FieldList() As String ' array to hold field names

Set setData = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblEnvironment WHERE 1 = 2")

intCount = 0
For Each fldTemp In setData.Fields
    ReDim Preserve FieldList(intCount + 1) ' expand the array for each field name
    FieldList(intCount) = fldTemp.Name
    intCount = intCount + 1
Next

BubbleSort FieldList 'sort the fieldnames

strFields = Join(FieldList, ",") 'join the names together with commas
strFields = Mid(strFields, 3)

For intCount = 1 To 10
    Controls("cboField" & intCount).RowSource = strFields
Next
```

the bubblesort code, just in case of link rot:

```
Sub BubbleSort(arr)
  Dim strTemp As String
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  Dim lngMin As Long
  Dim lngMax As Long
  lngMin = LBound(arr)
  lngMax = UBound(arr)
  For i = lngMin To lngMax - 1
    For j = i + 1 To lngMax
      If arr(i) > arr(j) Then
        strTemp = arr(i)
        arr(i) = arr(j)
        arr(j) = strTemp
      End If
    Next j
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly, excellent clean answer to the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you create a string array from `strFields`, you can then use `WizHook.SortStringArray` to sort the array.  I added a `SortStringArray` demo procedure down below.

You could use `SortStringArray` in your code like this ...

```vb
Dim astrFields() As String
astrFields = Split(strFields, ", ")
WizHook.SortStringArray astrFields
```

If you need it as a string again ...

```vb
strFields = Join(astrFields, ", ")
```

Or maybe you can get by with walking the array ...

```vb
For intCount = 0 To UBound(astrFields)
    Debug.Print intCount, astrFields(intCount)
Next
```

Information about `WizHook` is scare.  I created this sample procedure for its `SortStringArray` method when I was exploring `WizHook` mysteries.

```vb
Public Sub WizHook_SortStringArray()
   ' The WizHook Key is not required for this procedure.
   'WizHook.Key = 51488399
    Dim a(3) As String
    Dim i As Long
    a(0) = "zulu"
    a(1) = "alpha"
    a(2) = "gamma"
    a(3) = "delta"
    WizHook.SortStringArray a
    For i = 0 To 3
        Debug.Print a(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

I added in the comments from my original version of that procedure.  Some `WizHook` methods require a `Key` value.  However, I didn't believe `SortStringArray` does.  If it doesn't work as written, try enabling the `WizHook.Key` line.

Comment: Won't work without the key, which I edited your answer to include but you (or someone else) apparently rejected the edit.  ;o)

Comment: I never needed the `Key`, so believed it wasn't required for `SortStringArray`.  But I revised the answer since apparently it doesn't work for you without the `Key`.

Comment: This also works very smoothly.  It did not need a key at all.  I can only accept 1 answer, unfortunately but both your and Sean's solutions' are viable.  I'd not heard of WizHook before, it truly does seem undocumented in VBA, so I'm researching some more of its capabilities now to expand my knowledge base.  Thanks HansUp.

Comment: The most useful site I've found so far is in German but translates fairly well with Google Translate.  It seems much more comprehensive than most of the documentation I've found so far:  http://www.team-moeller.de/?Tipps_und_Tricks:Wizhook-Objekt&search=wizhook

Comment: You can open the Object Browser in the VB Editor IDE, right-click in the upper pane and select Show Hidden Members.  Although that's no substitute for actual documentation, it would at least let you see what's available if you want to explore `WizHook`.